# Can DFP slots be parameterized?

Tags: advertising, google-dfp

I am using Doubleclick For Publishers (small business) for serving ads on a news website. I want to server a certain ad only an article pages for a certain category. With openX I created a zone per category but I think this is very inflexible. Is it possible to parameterize a slot? Like calling `GA_googleFillSlot(SLOT_NAME, CATEGORY);` and parameterize a banner to be viewed in slot SLOT_NAME with category CATEGORY?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can set up to 20 different tags in DFP Small Business and target to those tags:

http://www.google.com/support/dfp_sb/bin/answer.py?answer=91225

If you are looking for more you can upgrade to the full DFP or checkout other options like OpenX (or my company [Adzerk](http://adzerk.com)).